# How to sync JWT token from container app to child app's session

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

We are implementing a microfrontend, microservices architecture.

App1 is the microfrontend app - ui built on React, backend built on spring boot.  It handles the authentication and provides the token to it's child app.  The token is generated using Jwts as follows:

```
Jwts.build().setClaims(claims).setSubject(username).setExpiration(expirationDate)...
```

App2 is a child app of the microfrontend setup.  It's ui is built on React, backend built on spring boot.  App1 attaches App2 via react-iframe while passing the token as follows:

```
<Iframe url={`${urlOfApp2}`?token={jwtToken}} ... />
```

App2 on `useEffect` checks if `window.location.search` has the `token` field and use this to set the Authenticcation in its security context.  This is done by calling endpoint `/user` in App2.  The App2 backend will then call an endpoint `/validate` from App1 to check if the token is valid.  If it is valid, App2 parses the token and creates  an `Authentication` object and saves it to its context as follows:

```
final Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

This will create the JSESSIONID.  So everytime an endpoint from App2 is requested, for example `/someendpoint`, it will check if the request has the required authority as set in the code above.  The security config is as follows:

```
http...
    .antMatchers("/user").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().hasAuthority("SOME_AUTHORITY_PARSED_FROM_THE_TOKEN")...
```

This works as the `/user` is called once to check if token is valid and a session on App2 is initialized.  So for succeeding requests, it will check if it has the proper authority.

The problem is, the session on App2 has different expiration compared to that set on the token.  How can we sync the expiration on the session on App2 with the token provided by App1?

Comment: what authentication service did you use? if you create your own authentication service you need to store the session to the database so the same user will get the same

Comment: Your spring security code looks fine, but I don't think this is a Java / Spring-Boot issue.  I think you need to get App2 to share cookies with App1. I think this is something to solve in React.

Answer (score 0):

Several things here;

1. You are exposing the token in cleartext (the iframe url). Even when HTTPS/TLS is used this URL itself is always cleartext and can be seen by anyone on the network at either end, or a middle party along the physical devices that relays network packets from client to server, anyone can see the token who are joined to the same wifi network as an example but the largest concern with exposing sensitive information in the URL is these URLs are logged everywhere, on the same device in unprotected files that other software can access, on all the devices on the network paths along the way (maybe even routed through countries you're not thinking can read this traffic), and on the server the same logs are created and often not protected either and these logs are almost always also sent of to a logging service like Datadog, SUMO, (hundreds others) who also see this sensitive token in the URL from these logs.

Bottom line, never, ever, send anything sensitive in a URL.

2. Which JWT scheme are you implementing for the client?

**a)** Is there a **private key** generated by the client and the public key sent to the server to form a JWT with encryption? Or;

**b)** Is it using a **HMAC** which is essentially a signature accompanying the data to provide an integrity check, which only ensures data was not modified, this type of JWT has no encryption and therefore the JWT is entirely 'readable' by anyone by design

**c)** There is **no actual authentication** happening on the client at all, the client is provided the JWT **to avoid** having to do it.

**If (a)** then the client generated a key/pair and it needs to send the public key to the server, not the server share anything with the client.

**If (b)** then the client needs the shared secret to complete the signing, it will generate the JWT 'token' itself new every time it makes a request to the microservices endpoints.

So you don't give a token to a client, the client generates (or rather constructs) it's own signature (the token) using the shared secret. The server also has the shared secret and can also construct and identical signature (token) on the server without the secret ever being sent over the communications channel with the data.

You will need to find an out-of-band method for a client to obtain the shared secret because sending it in the same communication method will defeat the entire purpose if having JWT.

**If (c)** This is not a use case for JWT. If you do not do actual authentication on the client, then the client-side is not proven to be 'authentic' using a security characteristic that is established to be a form of an authentication mechanism. Passing a string to a client endpoints from a server is only an authentication on the server, when the client later communicates using your method it is claiming it is the 'authentic' server who 'authenticated', which it is not, it is the client..

That's why JWT is not making sense in this situation. If **you do not** ever what to do the authentication on the client side, then the client must be treated as unauthenticated and don't need authorisation (JWT) because they have no authentic identity established and are indistinguishable from one another.

If **you do** want client side authorisation, you need client side authentication first. Maybe you are having trouble with implementation of Authentication on a client, you may find OIDC easier

Answer (score 0):

If App2 is the child, then App1 should dictate the auth expiration protocols. Why not just set your session expiration equal to your token expiration?  Each time a user logs in to App1, decode the JWT and pass the expiration as a variable to App2.

Or set a timeout equal to moments before expiration and silently pass token refresh requests until both expirations are nearly equal.

Also, don't pass tokens openly in this manner. Instead, pass encrypted headers or cookies. Or hash tokens and save them to a secure database for query or update as needed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to sync the JWT token expiration from the container app to the child app's session is to use a **session listener** on the child app that will **invalidate the session** when the token expires. A session listener is a class that implements the **HttpSessionListener** interface and can perform actions when a session is created or destroyed. You can register a session listener in your child app by adding a **@WebListener** annotation or by declaring it in your **web.xml** file.

To invalidate the session when the token expires, you can store the token expiration time as a **session attribute** when you create the session in the **/user** endpoint. Then, in the **sessionDestroyed** method of the session listener, you can compare the current time with the stored expiration time and invalidate the session if the token has expired. This way, the child app will not accept any requests from the session after the token expiration and will require a new token from the container app.

### Example

Here is an example of a session listener class that invalidates the session when the token expires:

```py
@WebListener
public class TokenExpirationSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    // do nothing
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    // get the session and the token expiration time
    HttpSession session = se.getSession();
    Long tokenExpiration = (Long) session.getAttribute("tokenExpiration");

    // check if the token has expired
    if (tokenExpiration != null && System.currentTimeMillis() > tokenExpiration) {
      // invalidate the session
      session.invalidate();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of how to store the token expiration time as a session attribute in the **/user** endpoint:

```py
// get the token from the query parameter
String token = request.getParameter("token");

// validate the token with the container app
boolean isValid = validateToken(token);

// if the token is valid, parse it and create the authentication object
if (isValid) {
  // parse the token and get the expiration time
  Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
  Long expiration = claims.getExpiration().getTime();

  // get the username and authorities from the claims
  String username = claims.getSubject();
  List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthoritiesFromClaims(claims);

  // create the authentication object and set it to the security context
  Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

  // get the session and store the token expiration time as a session attribute
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  session.setAttribute("tokenExpiration", expiration);
}
```